# Find the equation of the line in standard form with slope $m = -3$ and passing through the point $(1, \frac{1}{3})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am given the question "Find the equation of the line in standard form with slope $m = -3$ and passing through the point $(1, \frac{1}{3})$"

The solution is provided as $x + 3y = 2$

I arrived at $3y + 3x =4$

Here is my working:

point slope formula:
$y - y1 = m(x - x1)$

My given slope m is $-\frac{1}{3}$ and point is $(1, \frac{1}{3})$

So:

$y - \frac{1}{3} = -\frac{1}{3}(x - 1)$

I then multiplied both sides by 3 to get rid of the fractions:

$3(y - \frac{1}{3}) = 3(-\frac{1}{3}(x - 1))$

$3y - 1 = -3(x - 1)$

$3y - 1 = -3x + 3$

$3y = -3x + 4$

$3y + 3x = 4$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at $x + 3y = 2$?

Comment: Is the slope $-3$ or $-1 \over 3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake:    $ 3(-\frac{1}{3}(x - 1))= -(x-1),$
not 
$ -3(x - 1).$

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply both sides by $3$, you made a mistake in the RHS.